# R: populate data.frame within function in mapply

Tags: r, dataframe, mapply

A data.frame `df1` is queried (fuzzy match) against another data.frame `df2` with `agrep`. Via iterating over its output (a list called `matches` holding the row number of the respective matches in `df2`), `df1` is populated with affiliated values from `df2`.
The goal is a function that is passed to `mapply`; however, in all my attempts `df1` remains unchanged.

In a for-loop, the code works as expected and populates `df1` with the affiliated variables from `df2`. Still, I would be interested how to solve this with a function that is passed to `mapply`.

First, the two data.frames:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Species = c("Alisma plantago-aquatica", "Alnus glutinosa",
                                  "Carex davalliana", "Carex echinata",
                                  "Carex elata"),
                      CheckPoint = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                      L = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                      R = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                      K = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),
                 row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Species = c("Alisma gramineum", "Alisma lanceolatum",
                                  "Alisma plantago-aquatica", "Alnus glutinosa",
                                  "Alnus incana", "Alnus viridis",
                                  "Carex davalliana", "Carex depauperata",
                                  "Carex diandra", "Carex digitata",
                                  "Carex dioica", "Carex distans",
                                  "Carex disticha", "Carex echinata",
                                  "Carex elata"),
                      L = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 8L,
                            8L, 8L),
                      R = c(7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 6L, NA, 4L, 6L, 6L,
                            NA, NA),
                      K = c(6L, 2L, NA, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 4L, NA, 3L, NA,
                            3L, 2L)),
                 row.names = seq(1:15), class = "data.frame")
```

Then, fuzzy match by `Species`:

```
matches <- lapply(df1$Species, agrep, x = df2$Species, value = FALSE,
                 max.distance = c(deletions = 0,
                                  insertions = 1,
                                  substitutions = 1))
```

Populating `df1` with the values from `df2` works as expected:

```
for (i in 1:dim(df1)[1]){
  df1[i, 2:5] <- df2[matches[[i]], ]
  }
```

In contrast to my approach with `mapply` that does return the correct values, although as a list  of dissasembled values that are never written into `df1`. No combination (with or without `return(df1)`, writing it into another variable nor desparate attempts with the state of `SIMPLIFY` or `USE.NAMES`) yielded the desired results.

```
populatedf1 <- function(matches, index){
    df1[index, 2:5] <- df2[matches, ]
  #return(df1)
  }

mapply(populatedf1, matches, seq_along(matches), SIMPLIFY = FALSE,
              USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Would be great if someone knows the solution or could point me into a certain direction, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you would not need any loop here (`for` or `mapply`) if you replace `lapply` with `sapply` (so that it returns a vector instead of list) and then do a direct assignment.

```
matches <- sapply(df1$Species, agrep, x = df2$Species, value = FALSE,
                   max.distance = c(deletions = 0,
                                    insertions = 1,
                                   substitutions = 1))

df1[, 2:5] <- df2[matches,]
df1

#                   Species               CheckPoint L  R  K
#1 Alisma plantago-aquatica Alisma plantago-aquatica 7  5 NA
#2          Alnus glutinosa          Alnus glutinosa 5  5  3
#3         Carex davalliana         Carex davalliana 9  4  4
#4           Carex echinata           Carex echinata 8 NA  3
#5              Carex elata              Carex elata 8 NA  2
```

---

As far as your approach is concerned you can use `Map` or `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` and bring the list of dataframes into one dataframe using `do.call` and `rbind` and then assign.

```
df1[, 2:5] <- do.call(rbind, Map(populatedf1, matches, seq_along(matches)))
```

Comment: Cool, both of them do the job! And such a prompt response, thank you! :)